# How do I access checkbox on another form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've just made two forms and I have two checkboxes, I want they to copy eachother (if the checkBox in Form1 is checked, the checkBox in Form2 is checked)
I dont have a code for this but I can give you my Form1 name And Form2 name
Form1: MainUI
Form2: Settings

Comment: Use data-binding. Bind them to a boolean property of a single object. Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for the object.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. [Check out how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Have you tried solving the problem and ran into an obstacle? Paste the code you're having problems with to clarify!

Answer (score 0):

You need to fire an event from one form and handle it on the other form.

You'll need an event args class to carry the state of the checkbox:

```
public class CheckEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}
```

Then on your form that will be sending it's check state you'll need an event (let's assume that the Settings form will send it's checkbox state to the MainUI form) so Settings will need this adding:

```
public event EventHandler<CheckEventArgs> CheckboxChanged;
```

And on the CheckedChanged event of the checkBox you will fire the event:

```
public void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckboxChanged?.Invoke(this, new CheckEventArgs() { Checked = checkBox1.Checked });
}
```

On the form you want to receive the result from you'll need to handle that event (this code goes on MainUI):

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Form2 Settings = new Form2();
    Settings.CheckboxChanged += settings_CheckboxChanged;
}

public void settings_CheckboxChanged(object sender, CheckEventArgs e)
{
    checkBox1.Checked = e.Checked;
}
```

I would suggest that you don't use this to send in both directions without some modifications. Otherwise you will end up in an infinite loop firing the event back and forth between the two forms. Just use it in one direction and you'll be fine.

Comment: I'm pretty new to coding where should i put Settings.CheckboxChanged += settings_CheckboxChanged;

Comment: You instantiate your Settings form with `Form2 Settings = new Form2();` then put the `Settings.CheckboxChanged` line after that.

Comment: I've added a little extra code to show the Form1 constructor where you create Form2 (Settings) and add the event handler.

Comment: Thanks for that but i still get 1 error (sorry for my stupidity)
'EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Checked' and no accessible extension method 'Checked' accepting a first argument of type 'EventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: And i cant get this to work checkBox1.Checked = e.Checked;

Comment: You should be using `CheckEventArgs` not `EventArgs`. public void settings_CheckboxChange(object sender, `CheckEventArgs e`) Checked is a property of the CheckEventArgs class.